# How to use where statement in sybase

Tags: where-clause, sybase

```
SELECT top 100 status, title, priority
FROM delp_prod_techrisk_sentinel.CASE__all
WHERE status = closed
```

I am getting error msg:

> [Error] Script lines: 10-14 ------------------------  SQL Anywhere
>   Error -143: Column 'closed' not found  Msg: 207, Level: 16, State: 0 
>   Line: 0

What mistake am i doing ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with 'status = closed'? This means that a column named 'status' has the same value as a column named 'closed'.
Incidentally, 'where' is not a statement, but a clause that can be part of statements (like a SELECT statement, here)

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes in where condition -

```
SELECT top 100 status, title, priority
FROM delp_prod_techrisk_sentinel.CASE__all
WHERE status = 'closed'
```